# Issue in parsing JSON encoded date field in google chart

Tags: php, json, google-visualization

I am facing issue while implementing **'ChartRangeFilter'** control in google charts which uses date field as a Range filter. I am fetching data from MySQL database using JSON approach (JSON encoded data) and using it in view to render Line Chart in my Laravel application.

If I use Date field as String data type then it works but then I can not implement **'ChartRangeFilter'** as it only works with number and data type fields and due to this I have hard-coded whole data in my view with Date constructor. e.g.new Date(Year, Month, Day).

But hard-coding data is not feasible solution hence is there any alternative solution available in which I can use JSON encoded date field in **'ChartRangeFilter'**in google charts?

Here is my code snippet with hard-coded sample data.

```
function drawChart() {

    var jsonData = $.ajax({
    url: 'get_salesthree',
    dataType: 'json',
    async: false
                    }).responseText;

    var data = new google.visualization.DataTable(jsonData);
    var Data = new google.visualization.DataTable(); 

    Data.addRows([
    [new Date(2011, 01, 00),    9102,   0,      2150,   10026,  332,    5097,   28989,  16620,  90770,  1805,   0,      735,    30212,  9185,   5578 ]
```

Comment: please show us what `jsonData` looks like

Comment: @WhiteHat, kindly refer my below JSON data format string.                    {"cols":[{"label":"Date","type":"date"},{"label":"Chevrolet","type":"number"},{"label":"Datsun","type":"number"},{"label":"Fiat","type":"number"},{"label":"Ford","type":"number"},
"rows":[{"c":[{"v":"2011-01-31"},{"v":9102},{"v":0},{"v":2150},{"v":10026}]}]}

Comment: probably makes sense to add JSON to question rather than comment...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by Changing the Date format in my PHP code and then encoding it in JSON in such a way that it is understood by Google chart.

Here is my PHP Code snippet which contain changes in Date format while encoding it into JSON.

```
foreach($salesthree as $salethree)
{   

        $date = substr(($salethree->Datetime), 0, 10);
        $dateArr = explode('-', $date);
        $year = $dateArr[0];
        $month = $dateArr[1] - 1; // subtract 1 because javascript uses a zero-based index for months
        $day = $dateArr[2];
        $json['rows'][] = array('c' => array(
        array('v' => "Date($year, $month, $month)"),
        array('v' =>$salethree->Chevrolet),
        array('v' =>$salethree->Datsun),
        array('v' =>$salethree->Fiat),
        array('v' =>$salethree->Ford)
            ));
    }

    return $json;
 }
```

Now My JSON looks like.

```
 {"cols":[{"label":"Date","type":"date"},{"label":"Chevrolet","type":"number"},{"label":"Datsun","type":"number"},{"label":"Fiat","type":"number"},{"label":"Ford","type":"number"}],"rows":[{"c":[{"v":"Date(2011, 0, 31)"},{"v":9102},{"v":0},{"v":2150},{"v":10026},{"c":[{"v":"Date(2011, 1, 28)"},{"v":8634},{"v":0},{"v":1839},{"v":9293},{"c":[{"v":"Date(2011, 2, 31)"},{"v":8736},{"v":0},{"v":1860}]}]}
```